# How to handle this browser prompt in a WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

First and foremost I don't have much experience with website development and programming so this problem has taken me longer to solve than usual.

The website that my WebView targets is [student admin](https://maties2.sun.ac.za/rtad4/useradm/)

the page itself loads fine and everything works as planned, however the problem appears, clicking the "Sign on" link ("https://maties2.sun.ac.za/rtad4/useradm/auth")

on a browser, a prompt is created at the top for input:
[image]

clicking cancel yields this page:

[image]

however, on my WebView, clicking "Sign on" immediately loads the cancel page:

[image]

which leads me to believe that I need to explicitly handle these kind of events in my code? the problem is I'm not really understanding them or what is creating them (javascript?) I had a look through the page with chromes inspect element but I couldn't figure out what triggered the popups

any ideas?

Comment: This is not created through Javascript. You can verify it by disabling js opening this chrom url bar chrome://settings/content

Answer (score 1):

User the appropriate WebView method:

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
            handler.proceed("username", "password");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tried this, had no effect on result

Answer (score -2):

The reason you are getting Authentication required popup on top of window is because "**[Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)**" is enabled for that domain.

You need to disable **basic authentication** for that site.

Comment: any idea on how to do it?

Comment: OP's question was how to handle a basic authentication prompt in a WebView, not how to disable basic authentication on a website.