# Authentication autofill with Selenium in Safari

Tags: selenium, authentication, testing, safari

I am searching for solution about testing in Selenium JS. I need to log in after get some url.
I've tried already with:

`await driver.get("https://login:password@server.net");`

and it works with Chrome and Firefox, however, unfortunately not with Safari.

[image]

Comment: the login form is part of the page or a popup?

Comment: It's a popup. Default from browser.

Comment: are you on java? on python there pyautogui which let you interact with the UI (popups included), try to find if there is something similar on java

Comment: I use JavaScript. It has to be Selenium :|

Comment: Browser's prompt popups don't have a html hence cannot be controlled with selenium (talking about these kind of popups https://www.google.com/search?q=browser+prompt&sxsrf=AJOqlzUtB0ZhZqRMvi0dIqrQOpKm93_RAQ:1674056880307&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNzLztu9H8AhXxSvEDHedyAv8Q_AUoAXoECAIQAw&cshid=1674056938679154&biw=1707&bih=828&dpr=1.13)

Comment: did you try with `seleniumwire`? is your site a proxy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771326/how-to-handle-this-browser-prompt-in-a-webview
It is that kind of thing. It is a proxy.
There is a problem only in Safari. It works in Firefox and Chrome.